# Avoid text wrapping in a flex box (Tailwind CSS)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a title with some content inside of a flex box, and I don't want my title (`Writing Stuff`) to wrap. Any idea on why this is happening and how to resolve it? Ideally "Writing Stuff" would be shown on one line. Here's the [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/)

[image]

Edit: I know I can just set `whitespace: nowrap` but is that the best way to do it?